Problema en Python con la página que se abre cuando estoy haciendo web scraping con Selenium
Tengo este código:
service = Service(executable_path = path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service)

# Página web con la que establecemos la conexión
web = "https://web.archive.org/web/20221115040351/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup"
driver.get(web)

# Data de todos los partidos
matches = driver.find_elements(by = "xpath", 
                               value = "//div[@class=\"footballbox\"]")

Luego de esto tengo el código para buscar y extraer la info que me interesa y al final lo siguiente:
time.sleep(2) # Establezco una espera 
driver.quit() # Cierro la conexión 

Y mi problema es que se me abre el chrome for Testing pero digamos en la pagina de inicio, no me lleva a la web que le he dicho que vaya, y se queda ahí el código que nunca termina la ejecución. Tengo que interrumpir la ejecución manualmente
Este es un proyecto que he estado viendo para aprender y practicar, soy novato y no sé cómo resolver este problema. Gracias de antemano

Si solo quieres extraer información de una página, sin interactuar con ella, mejor usa Beautiful Soup (BS4).

Ya hice lo mismo con BeautifulSoup antes de ponerme con Selenium. Es para practicar pero muchas gracias igualmente por tu respuesta!!

tuve un problema parecido. Si estas usando VS Code haz crtl + shift + p y escribe "jupyter" para intentar abrir un Jyper Notebook por que el editor tiene algunos bugs que no permiten trabajar cómodamente con selenium.
Edit:
La razón por la cual se utiliza Selenium para hacer Web Scrapping es por la necesidad de interactuar dinámicamente con el javascript de la página. Por tanto , para sitios donde el HTML es estático es mejor usar BeatifulSoup que es mucho mas rápido.
Voy a mostrarte las 2 formas de hacer web scrapping en la web donde haces referencia.
Usando Selenium:
 from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # opcional, sirve para usar el teclado
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    options.page_load_strategy = 'eager' # Espera que se carguen todos los #elementos del DOM, en este caso también es opcional pero en casos particulares es útil.
    
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    browser.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20221115040351/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup")

 find_footballbox = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class=\"footballbox\"]")

    for i in find_footballbox:
        print(find_footballbox.text)

    browser.quit()

Usando BeatifulSoup:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as scrap

url = requests.get("https://web.archive.org/web/20221115040351/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup")

url_parse = scrap(url.text, "html.parser")

find_footballbox = url_parse.find_all("div", class_="footballbox")
print(find_footballbox.text)

Puedes cambiar find() por find_all() si lo precisas.
Si necesitas entender mas sobre bs4 te dejo la documentación que está en español:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.es/
Espero que de algo te haya servido

Muchas gracias Elias, voy a mirar todo esto ya que ambas formas son algo diferentes a la que he visto para hacer webscraping. Muchas gracias!!

También puedes usar Playwright que es de Microsoft y considero que es mas fácil de utilizar que selenium y puedes hacer prácticamente lo mismo pero con una sintaxis menos verbosa. Saludos.
